# Efficient way to write to the file on server-side on specified event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on short quiz on website. User will get the question on the screen and then will have to push one of the buttons e.g. Y / N. There will be timer which get user time to correct answer, and then I want to save result to the file. There will be few questions..

I want to generate few slides with questions (javascript/jQuery), after correct answer save the time to file, and slide to the next question - but it's on client side so I came up with to use ajax, run php method after correct answer and pass time of the answer to this method.

It is good idea to do it in this way? Maybe my concept in general is wrong? I think about php and /js/jquery because I have some experience in this technologies but if there are any other ways (easy to understand ;) ) please mention it.

By the way, I'm not looking for solution but for suggestions :)

Comment: What you describe sounds fine to me. AJAX is great for things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax to post updates to your remote PHP script. 
The php script will write data inside your file (or database).

I think your way is the right one.